# Random Variable Practice Exam question

Tags: probability, statistics

I am trying to go over the practice exam and I need help!

If $X$ is a continuous random variable with a density that is symmetric about
some point, $\xi$ , show that $\mathbb{E}X = \xi$ , provided that $\mathbb{E}X$ exists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty x f(x)\,dx = \int_{-\infty}^\infty (\xi+u)f(\xi+u)\,du = \xi \underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(\xi+u)\,du} + \int_{-\infty}^\infty u f(\xi+u)\,du.
$$
The constant $\xi$ can be pulled out of the integral over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ because it is constant, i.e. it does not change as $u$ goes from $-\infty$ to $\infty$.  And the integral over the $\underbrace{\text{underbrace}}$ is equal to $1$, so the whole thing is
$$
\xi + \int_{-\infty}^\infty u f(\xi+u)\,du.
$$
This last integral is
$$
\int_{-\infty}^0 u f(\xi+u)\,du + \int_0^\infty u f(\xi+u)\,du. \tag 1  
$$
That first integral is
\begin{align}
& \int_{-\infty}^0 u f(\xi+u)\,du = \int_\infty^0 (-w)f(\xi-w)(-dw) = \int_\infty^0 wf(\xi-w)\,dw \\[10pt]
= {} & -\int_0^\infty wf(\xi-w)\,dw = -\int_0^\infty wf(\xi+w)\,dw = -\int_0^\infty u f(\xi+u)\,du.
\end{align}
Thus the sum of the two integrals in $(1)$ is $0$, and so $\mathbb E\,X=\xi$.

The exception would be when the two integrals are $+\infty$ and $-\infty$.  Then $\mathbb EX$ would not exist.  When that happens then
$$
\lim_{a,b\to\infty}\left(\int_{-a}^0 u f(\xi+u)\,du + \int_0^b u f(\xi+u)\,du.\right)
$$
actually depends on the relative rates at which $a$ and $b$ go to $\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

You have that $\mathbb{E}X = \int_\mathbb{R} xf_X(x)\, dx$. Making the substitution $x-\xi = y$ and using the fact that $f_X(x)$ is symmetric about $\xi$ should give you the desired result.

Comment: I am still confused?